# Can Azure SQL support more than 5 TB as storage limit?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Azure SQL database supports 5TB as the storage limit. Is it possible to work with Microsoft Support and increase that limit/quota by any means?

Comment: Normal limit of SQL DB should be 4TB, btw. Or were did you get the 5TB limit from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bigger workloads there is SQL Database Hyperscale with up to 100 TB storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale#what-are-the-hyperscale-capabilities

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on your own or create a support ticket to do that, check the pricing [`documentation`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/managed/).